# How to delete a global variable from inside a function in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I want to delete the global variable ResultsTree but now the following code yells that ResultsTree is not defined in a_func when I go to update it:

```
import mcst_data

ResultsTree = mcst_data.NonBinTree(-1)


def a_func():

    #some stuff
    ResultsTree.update(var1,var2)


def another_func():

    global ResultsTree

    for i in range(10000):
        a_func()

    bestAns = ResultsTree.get()
    
    ## need to delete ResultsTree from memory here
    del ResultsTree

    return bestAns
```

---

```
#main file:

import subfile

main():
       subfile.another_func()
```

Comment: You are getting that error because you are deleting the `ResultsTree` completely. When you try to update a variable that is deleted, of course, you will see that the variable is not defined. I may be able to help you further if I see how these functions are called.

Comment: it is called from another file. The subfile is called many times from the main file. Every time it is called I need it to delete TreeResults at the end of the call because it uses up a lot of memory, and needs to start with no values when subfile is called. I added code representing this.

Comment: This does not directly answer your question, but is it not possible to move the `ResultsTree = mcst_data.NonBinTree(-1)` statement to `another_func()` and then pass that variable to `a_func()`?  It appears to be a mutable object, so it will be updated in-place and then you can delete it after you run the `get()` method.  It will be re-initialized at the beginning of `another_func()`.

Comment: @AlexK this worked. Thanks. I can delete the variable now, although garbage collection is not working yet according to memory on my pc